# How many process will be used when command having pipes is executed in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, process

How many process will be used when "cat filename | grep poem | wc -l " command is executed in unix. 
Will there be 1 process, 2 processes , 3 processes...... to execute the above command.

Comment: At least one too many, since you do not have to use `cat` in your example.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the shell.  In bash there should be 3 processes.  I ran 3 sleeps in place of those commands in the background and ran `pstree` after.  This is what I got:

```
> sleep 4s | sleep 4s | sleep 4s & pstree
 │         ├─bash───bash─┬─pstree
 │         │             ├─3*[sleep]
```

In a subshell:

```
> ( sleep 4s | sleep 4s | sleep 4s ) & pstree
 │         ├─bash───bash─┬─bash───3*[sleep]
 │         │             ├─pstree
```

Update:

This didn't properly demonstrate the behavior of bash when executing pipelines since placing them in a background can affect the number of subshells executed.  I suggest running them in the foreground then checking the number of processes in another terminal when observing.  Bash may optimize execution of pipelines by preventing unnecessary use of subshells, probably in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe takes the output stream from the first process and makes it an input stream for the next process.  You're guaranteed a process per command, but each of those processes may create child processes depending on their operation.

Comment: There's three started, But since he's saying "used" maybe we should count one for the shell that puts everything together?

Comment: @user814064 good point.  I suppose it's a relative question though.  We'd need more information to be more specific.  I've changed my solution to be a little more generic.